# Can git log work when providing two refs in the wrong order?

Tags: git

I am writing an automated system to list commits between two commit references. Say I have 3 commits in chronological order such as:

- A
- B
- C

and I do `git log --pretty=oneline A..C`, I get the log as expected. However if I reverse the arguments, for example `git log --pretty=oneline C..A`, I get nothing. Is there no way git can be clever about the commit references?

If not, is there a way to determine if ref C should be after A in the argument list automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run

```
git merge-base A C
```

- if it returns A, then you sould call `git log A..C`
- if it returns C, then you sould call `git log C..A`
- if it returns something else, A and C are on different branches and `merge-base` returned their common ancestor

Answer (score 2):

While the symmetric difference ( `...` ) is not the same, you can use it in this case:

```
git log A...C
git log C...A
```